# Why does it keep adding a random 0?

Tags: javascript, math, jsfiddle, median

I was trying to build an MCT calculator in javascript, however during the creation of the median, I kept getting errors. This is my code: (Keep in mind I am relatively new to javascript)

```
var min = prompt("Enter minimum value");
var max = prompt("Enter maximum value");
if (min > max) {
    alert("Error:\n\n\nMinimum value '" + min + "' is greater than Maximum value '" + max + "'");
} else {
    var a = (max - min);
    alert("variable a is " + max + " - " + min + " = " + a);
    var b = a / 2;
    alert("variable b is " + a + " / 2 = " + b);
    var c = min + b;
    alert("variable c is " + min + " + " + b + " = " + c);
    alert("Range is " + a + "\n\nMedian is " + c + "\n\nMin is " + min + "\n\n Max is " + max);
}
```

If you type in 5 for minimum value and 10 for maximum value, it will tell you 5 is larger than 10, but it isn't.. And if you type 10 for minimum value and 15 for maximum value, it will have the median be 102.5 rather than 12.5 I do not get this at all, please help :)

Comment: @Stijn: That the **answer** to another question also answers this one doesn't imply that this **question** is a duplicate.

Comment: @ScottSauyet The question is also the same if you ignore the story surrounding the actual question.

Comment: @Stijn: obviously enough people agreed with you to close the question, but I still don't think that a question asking, "Why is arithmetic not working for my numbers?" is even close to a duplicate of one asking, "Why aren't my strings being treated as numbers?"  The latter is already much closer to a solution than the former.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I gave this some more thought and I agree now. Just casted the final reopen vote.

Comment: @Stijn: Cool.  I think a good answer (or comment) to this sort of thing could easily be just a link to a different question whose answer also answers this one, or a direct link to that answer.  But I'd rather not frighten off newbies unnecessarily.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try using numbers, not strings:

```
var min = parseInt(prompt("Enter minimum value"), 10);
var max = parseInt(prompt("Enter maximum value") , 10);
```

Or, if you want to allow for floats:

```
var min = parseFloat(prompt("Enter minimum value"));
var max = parseFloat(prompt("Enter maximum value"));
```

This because strings are compared lexicographically, using their numerical character codes, rather than the value of the number itself.

Comment: lexicographical != natural/numeric ordering :-)

Answer (score 1):

The [`prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.prompt) function returns a string, and strings are compared according to the Unicode code points of each character in the string (also called [lexicographical or alphabetical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)). The code point of `"5"` is greater than the code point of `"1"`, so the string `"5"`  actually *is* greater than the string `"10"` (i.e. comes after it in lexicographical ordering) .

Try parsing the inputs like this:

```
var min = parseFloat(prompt("Enter minimum value"));
var max = parseFloat(prompt("Enter maximum value"));
```